# MIPS: Editing files

Tags: mips, file-handling

I can't find a source to learn how to edit files on MIPS.
So far I have a code that write on a file, but it just overwrite the file and not actually just modify some parts.

What I wanted to is for example, the text file has:
Happy 20th Birthday!

and I wanted to change it to be:
Happy 21st Birthday!

What can I do to just modify a part and not overwrite the whole file?
or is there a file-pointer that I can use? If so, how can does it work?

Comment: It's probably irrelevant that you run on MIPS but much more relevant is the programming language and maybe the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIPS Mars simulator does not provide [syscalls](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) to modify a file. You can only read or write.

To do what you need, read the entire file into memory, modify the data in memory then write the modified data to a (new) file.